# Upgrading module from EE2 > EE3

Tags: ee2, add-on-development, module, plugin, ee3

Can I confirm that if a custom module does not have a control panel interface, conversion from EE2 > EE3 only requires the following changes:

- Create a *addon.setup.php* file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally yes, you only need to add addon.setup.php. There of course could be some deprecated code etc.